# Why is spec_helper having this ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

Would anyone want to make use of spec_helper in other environments than test, or why is it configured like that? To allow custom test environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An environment can have any possible name. You can use multiple test environments or even give your test environment another name than simply `test`. Because it's convention to name your test environment `test` doesn't mean you can't choose to name it differently.